# Is it different a SQL query inside of stored procedure than a SQL executed from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Let me explain.

I used a large SELECT sentence with multiple joins inside my PHP code. It's big because some joins depends on some values from first tables (something like `if table1.column_a=1 then alias_b=table2.column_a, if table1.column_a=2 then alias_b=table3.column_b, ...)` and because I send condition from my `html` form which can be changed dynamically (sometimes it could just have `some_date>='2017/09/01'`, but it could turn into something more complex like `some_date>='2017/09/01'` and (name like `J%on` not `sec_name='Doe'`) ...").

I received the instruction of make a stored procedure for this query and for more time i take analyze this i can't find some way for make this query dynamic without putting it inside of string into the stored procedure and receiving the WHERE condition as stored procedure parametter (in the stored procedure i have somthing like `SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ... JOIN ... JOIN... WHERE ',param_condition); PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;..." )`

My question is... is this the same as sending the `sql` from php?

Comment: If you need to send parts of the actual SQL-query to the stored procedure, then you've done something wrong (and it would be a pain to debug). If you have different cases, then you can create different stored procedures for those cases and simply call the one that's relevant at the time. Alternatively, make the procedure itself decide what to do depending on the input variables.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in fact i was constructing the SQL inside my PHP code but, as i mentioned, i received the instruction to make a stored procedure. I Think that stored procedures and dynamic querys are two things that aren't related at all. The goal of my PHP module is allow to the user to query information in different ways that can possible fit any necessity using one or more criteria inside the where clausule. Any other approach recomendation is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: _"I received the instruction"_ - from who and why?

Comment: *"I Think that stored procedures and dynamic querys are two things that aren't related at all"*  You might want to reconsider that thought.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson from partners that started the project. But after a little chat i realized they know the points mentioned by Barmar.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ok, i mean about optimization. In this case there is no need to convert my dynamic SQL query to stored procedure for performance improvement. I know it can be done, but because of criteria changes, there wil be no only one execution plan.

Comment: Correct, it is not relevant for performance.  However, stored procedures do not have execution plans in MySQL, and every query gets a new plan every time it is executed, regardless of how the query is created/prepared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, preparing and executing a statement from a stored procedure is pretty much the same as sending the query from PHP. The only difference is whether the work of concatenating all the pieces is done in the PHP code running on the client, or the MySQL server.

If the contents of the query being constructed is dependent on other table data, it may be better to do it in a stored procedure, so you don't need multiple round trips between the database and PHP to get all the information.

But if it's only dependent on parameters already available in PHP, it's probably best to construct the query in PHP, if only because (IMHO) the PHP syntax is likely to be easier to understand. The performance difference should be minor -- string concatenation is simple for both PHP and MySQL. But I generally think that anything that isn't dependent on SQL data should not be done in the database server.